# changing forms attribute in django formset

Tags: django-forms, django-templates

can anyone suggest me how to modify forms attribute of django formset, in a **template**?

**my scenario:**
i wanted to dynamically create more forms using javascript, than which is loaded from model_formset.

so, if i loaded 3 forms using model formset from server, then using javascript i created one more form and changed the **TOTAL** forms value in management formset.

**problem:**
i had to run for loop on formset.forms before and after creating the additional form using javascript.

but the loop runs only 3 times (when there are 4 now and after updating **TOTAL** forms value).

So, what should i change in management forms for the 'forms' attribute to know there are actually 4 forms now. because i will use the **{{ formset.prefix }}** in the loop. and i should have say, **type-4** for the **4th** form.

thanks!

EDIT: SOLVED! see comment.

Comment: it seems the formset.forms is preloaded with a list of objects, and this has nothing to do with management forms. so to use a for loop on formset before and after adding forms and updating TOTAL forms (using javascript), we need to use a javascript for loop on TOTAL form count!